# compiling clutter gui on linux with code blocks: Compiles, but doesn't load images etc, same code working fine on visual studio

Tags: linux, codeblocks, clutter

I have written a gui using the clutter library on widows using visual studio.

I am now trying to compile it on a linux virtual machine using code blocks.  It compiles fine, but the program launches with only a few actors, almost a blank window.

I did a quick test program, and found that I can load textures, and do animations, and effects, no problem.

I cannot figure out what is causing the failure.

I tried eliminating everything except the very basic start page, and it worked.  So I went back and started commenting out certain parts until I could find what's not working, but after commenting out a few thousand lines worth of code I gave up.

I am also new to code blocks, and linux, and I am wondering what is the best way to go about figuring this out?

And, Code blocks prints out a bunch of warning messages when compiling, but they all go away in about 2 seconds, and I can't read them.

Any tips.

Comment: You'll have to figure out some way to get _all_ warning messages from your compiler, or you'll be doomed to _guessing_ what your problems are for all eternity. Most terminal programs let you change the size of scrollback and most programs just write messages to standard out or standard error; try adding `>/tmp/out 2>/tmp/err` to your compile command, and see if the warnings are in `/tmp/err` or `/tmp/out`. Can you write a twenty-line program to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm starting to get the hang of code blocks a little bit.  I've found that some of my problems were due to capitals/lowercase mismatching with a few of the files, and now I am down to one last problem.  `MV_CL_GUI->ProjectName = clutter_text_get_text(CLUTTER_TEXT(MV_CL_GUI->Actor_Text)); clutter_stage_set_title(CLUTTER_STAGE(MV_CL_GUI->Stage_MainMenu), MV_CL_GUI->ProjectName.c_str());`  this works on windows for me.  I don't know, I'll need to do some thinking about it.  `ProjectName` is a string.

Comment: I just found a solution: `clutter_stage_set_title(CLUTTER_STAGE(MV_CL_GUI->Stage_MainMenu), clutter_text_get_text(CLUTTER_TEXT(MV_CL_GUI->Actor_Text)));`

Comment: if you found a solution can you post it as an answer, also can you edit your question a bit, having trouble parsing it